# HTML <input type="file"> how to get filename right after file was chosen

Tags: events, file, input, types

This is my input tag:

```
<input id="myId" class="button" name="myFile" type="file">
```

As soon as the user chooses a file, I would like to get the name of the file, to display it and give the user some feedback.
I know that I can get the filename in Javascript (using Jquery) like so:

```
var fileName = $('#myId').val();
```

However, I would like to do a function call as soon, as the user picks a file. If a add an onclick-even at the "myId" Tag, this event will get called as soon as the user clicks the button, but BEFORE he picks a file.
What event is being triggered when the user chooses a file? How can I call a function right after the user picks a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery, the solution is quite straight forward:

```
$("#myId").change(function(){
   doIt();
 });
```